# Replacing some string in a text file shifts the remaining text to next line

Tags: perl

I am trying to replace a string in a text file using Perl script. The value gets replaced successfully. However, it shifts the remaining text of the line to the next line. I want the line to be intact as before. Can someone help?

`sample_file_dml` has the below text in it:

```
seq_no,1,1,GET,xyz
seq_no,1,2,PUT,xyz
```

I want to replace `seq_no` in each line with the value of variable `seq_no_value`. This value is obtained through some calculations in my code (for example - 9999).

Expected output:

```
9999,1,1,GET,xyz
9999,1,2,PUT,xyz
```

But, I am getting the below output:

```
9999
,1,1,GET,xyz
9999
,1,2,PUT,xyz
```

Code snippet used:

```
        open my $IN, '<', $sample_dml_file or die $!;
        open my $OUT, '>>', $new_dml_file or die $!;
        
        while (<$IN>) {
            s/\b(seq_no)\b/$seq_no_value/g;
            print {$OUT} $_;
        }
        close $OUT or die $!;
```

Answer (score 4):

I believe `$seq_no_value` also has a newline character in it at the end (`\n`).  You can remove it with [chomp](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp):

```
chomp $seq_no_value;
```

Perhaps you were reading lines of a file when you set the variable.

Here is a self-contained example:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my $seq_no_value = "9999\n";
chomp $seq_no_value;
while (<DATA>) {
    s/\b(seq_no)\b/$seq_no_value/g;
    print $_;
}

__DATA__
seq_no,1,1,GET,xyz
seq_no,1,2,PUT,xyz
```

This outputs:

```
9999,1,1,GET,xyz
9999,1,2,PUT,xyz
```

If you comment out the `chomp` line, you get your original results.